# Updating 3 forms using formsets in view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a view that adds 3 different model objects using 3 ModelForms and formsets: here is it:

```
@login_required
def nouveaudossier(request):
    DocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(DocumentdeBase, form=DocumentdebaseForm, extra=5)
    PhotoAvantFormSet = modelformset_factory(PhotoAvant, form=PhotoAvantForm, extra=5)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
        if dossierForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():
            dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
            dossier_form.created_by = Prestataire.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            dossier_form.save()
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form:
                    image = form['documentdebase_image']
                    photo = DocumentdeBase(dossier=dossier_form, documentdebase_image=image)
                    photo.save()
            for form2 in formset2.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form2:
                    image2 = form2['photoavant_image']
                    photo2 = PhotoAvant(dossier=dossier_form, photoavant_image=image2)
                    photo2.save()
            messages.success(request,
                             "Dossier créé!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(dossierForm.errors, formset.errors, formset2.errors)
    else:
        dossierForm = DossierForm()
        formset = DocumentFormSet(queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'dashboard/nouveau_dossier.html',
                  {'dossierForm': dossierForm, 'formset': formset, 'formset2': formset2})
```

Now, I want to make an update view, where it takes the same form, and populates it with data existing from the 3 models, and the user can make changes. Here is what I did, I added an instance to the form, and a pk attribute to the function:

```
@login_required
def reviserdossier(request, pk):
    DocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(DocumentdeBase, form=DocumentdebaseForm, extra=5)
    PhotoAvantFormSet = modelformset_factory(PhotoAvant, form=PhotoAvantForm, extra=5)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance_dossier = Dossier.objects.get(pk=pk)
        dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST, instance=instance_dossier)
        instance_document = DocumentdeBase.objects.get(pk=pk)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance_document)
        instance_photo = PhotoAvant.objects.get(pk=pk)
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance_photo)
        if dossierForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():
            dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
            dossier_form.created_by = Prestataire.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            dossier_form.save()
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form:
                    image = form['documentdebase_image']
                    photo = DocumentdeBase(dossier=dossier_form, documentdebase_image=image)
                    photo.save()
            for form2 in formset2.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form2:
                    image2 = form2['photoavant_image']
                    photo2 = PhotoAvant(dossier=dossier_form, photoavant_image=image2)
                    photo2.save()
            messages.success(request, "Dossier mis à jour!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(dossierForm.errors, formset.errors, formset2.errors)
    else:
        dossierForm = DossierForm()
        formset = DocumentFormSet(queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'dashboard/reviser_dossier.html',
                  {'dossierForm': dossierForm, 'formset': formset, 'formset2': formset2})
```

When I run the view, I get this error:

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

Here is my traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/dossiers/reviser/7

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'photologue']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\verautov0\verautonoapi\dashboard\views.py" in reviserdossier
  776.         formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance_document)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __init__
  569.         super().__init__(**{'data': data, 'files': files, 'auto_id': auto_id, 'prefix': prefix, **kwargs})

Exception Type: TypeError at /dossiers/reviser/7
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

Here is the new code I did and still the same problem persists:

```
@login_required
def reviserdossier(request, pk):
    DocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(DocumentdeBase, form=DocumentdebaseForm, extra=5)
    PhotoAvantFormSet = modelformset_factory(PhotoAvant, form=PhotoAvantForm, extra=5)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
        if dossierForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():
            dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
            dossier_form.created_by = Prestataire.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            dossier_form.save()
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form:
                    image = form['documentdebase_image']
                    photo = DocumentdeBase(dossier=dossier_form, documentdebase_image=image)
                    photo.save()
            for form2 in formset2.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form2:
                    image2 = form2['photoavant_image']
                    photo2 = PhotoAvant(dossier=dossier_form, photoavant_image=image2)
                    photo2.save()
            messages.success(request, "Dossier mis à jour!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(dossierForm.errors, formset.errors, formset2.errors)
    else:
        instance_dossier = Dossier.objects.get(pk=pk)
        dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST, instance=instance_dossier)
        instance_document = DocumentdeBase.objects.get(pk=pk)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance_document)
        instance_photo = PhotoAvant.objects.get(pk=pk)
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance_photo)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/reviser_dossier.html',
                  {'dossierForm': dossierForm, 'formset': formset, 'formset2': formset2})
```

Comment: I think you should populate the form on GET and handle the updated data on POST.

Comment: i can use the if request.method == GET but how?

Comment: Yes, you should populate there. Check this link (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) at the first code example, the chunk of code where it says "# Creating a form to change an existing article." I think you should do this into your GET. Sorry typos, I am writing from my phone. I will post an answer later.

Comment: No other solutions people?

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the form this way in your view:

```
if request.method == 'GET': # You first time load the update page
    dossier     = Dossier.objects.get(pk=pk)
    dossierForm = DossierForm(instance=dossier)
    ...

if request.method == 'POST':
    dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST)
    ... # Validation, save...
```

Comment: Well this is what I did, and it gave me the error specified above.
I'll update the question with the new code.